# Expose ModifiedOn column from Orleans IPersistentState

Tags: asp.net-core, ado.net, orleans

The question is pretty self defining, what would be the easiest way to expose the `ModifiedOn` column in the `IPersistentState` object I inject in to the `Grain` using `[PersistentState("stateType", "OrleansPersistance")] IPersistentState<stateType> stateTypeState`? I already have access to the `Etag`but would like to access this `modifiedOn` column or add other custom columns. The rationale behind is I'd like to have a peace of code as the following:

```
if((Datetime.Utc.Now - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) >= _myState.ModifiedOn) RefreshState();
```

Comment: This is not a bug that needs reproduction, just an example on how could I get access to the `modifiedOn` column from the IPersistentState which doesn't exist at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Since timestamp isn't [presented in the interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/grains/grain-persistence/?pivots=orleans-7-0#api), I suggest you two options:

- add a `timestamp` into the state model
- or keep the timestamp as a private property in the grain; yes, it will be lost if grain is moved to another silo or it's deactivated for some reason but it depends on your business requirements, i.e. whether this edge case critical for you or not.